# How do I inherit a method from a different class file?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver

Ok guys firstly I am sorry I am not too great with c#.  Basically I have 2 class files, lets call one TestBase and the other TestScripts1.  Within class TestScripts1 it inherits the initializer TestBase so all my scripts can run. Now in reverse I want to use one of my methods called DragAssignDeviceAndDriver() in TestScripts1 and use it in TestBase .  Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is my code for the initializer from class TestBase :

```
[TestClass]
    public class TestBase
    {        
        [TestInitialize]
        public void BaseTestInit()
        {
            // create chrome driver
            //driver = new ChromeDriver();

            ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
            opt.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
            opt.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            opt.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

            LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet(driver);
            //GenerationTestData();
        }


      }

        public void LoginAndGenerateTestData(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            DragAssignDeviceAndDriver();
        }
```

Above how do I inherit the method DragAssignDeviceAndDriver();

And here is my code class TestScripts1 -  as you can see TestScripts1 inherits TestBase already:

```
    [TestClass]
    public class TestScripts1: TestBase
    {

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {

           (_regRep.organizationOption, "Amazing Power", driver);

        }


        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("Cat1")]
        public void DragAssignDeviceAndDriver()
        {
         //Do stuff   

        }
```

Comment: You seem to be using inheritance incorrectly...

Comment: inheritance works the other way around. If TestScripts1 inherits from TestBase then TestScript1 can call methods from TestBase but not the other way around.

Comment: @gsharp so what you are saying is the only way I can do this is copy my method and place inside my TestBase?

Comment: No I'm not saying that. Why don't you put the code in a helper class and then call it from DragAssignDeviceAndDriver and also from LoginAndGenerateTestData ? Or  implement it in TestBase and use it in TestScript1..

Comment: I think you need to clarify the issue. Can you draw a diagram or otherwise explain in plain English what the requirements are?

Answer (score 1):

You "can't" call a method, defined in an derivative class, from the base class. The base class needs to know how it should be called. It should be declared in the base class and to be overridden in the derivative class.

In this case, when the base class doesn't have any default implementation, you could declare it as abstract. *(since it is a base class, it would not constructed directly)*

This way the base class can call the overridden method.

For example:

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class TestBase
{       
    protected abstract void DragAssignDeviceAndDriver();

    [TestInitialize]
    public void BaseTestInit()
    {
        // create chrome driver
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();

        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
        opt.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
        opt.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

        LoginAndSelectAutomationFleet(driver);
        //GenerationTestData();
    }

    public void LoginAndGenerateTestData(IWebDriver driver)
    {
       DragAssignDeviceAndDriver();
    }

  }
```

---

```
[TestClass]
public class TestScripts1: TestBase
{

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {

       (_regRep.organizationOption, "Amazing Power", driver);  // <--- ??

    }


    [TestMethod]
    [TestCategory("Cat1")]
    protected override void DragAssignDeviceAndDriver()
    {
     //Do stuff   

    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member TestBase.DragAssignDeviceAndDriver()

Comment: @Butler true that, I've changed it... the it should be `protected override void...`

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0534 'GenerateTestData' does not implement inherited abstract member 'TestBase.DragAssignDeviceAndDriver()' UnitTestProj C:\Users\NAME\source\repos\AmazingPower.Hub.AutomationTests\UnitTestProj\GenerateTestData.cs doesn't work when I run any child method